# primefaces creating a dynamic dashboard

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces, ejb-3.0

Following the example at http://www.wobblycogs.co.uk/index.php/computing/jee/49-dynamic-dashboard-with-primefaces im trying to create a dynamic dashboard.

Copying the code works 100% perfeclty, but im trying to use it with my own implementation.

When i load my index page it dosnt show any panels or the dashboard at all. When i navigate to a differet page, and come back the elements appear!

I have no idea why the dashboard is not displayed on initial page load.

Im working with Jboss 5.1, EJB 3.0, JSF 2.0 and Primefaces 3.4.

This is the top of my controller class:

```
@Model
@ViewController(viewId = "/pages/index.xhtml")
public class MonitorController implements Serializable, ViewInitializer, ViewFinalizer {
@Inject
private transient MonitorService monitorService;
@Inject
private transient MonitorUserService monitorUserService;
@Inject
private transient MonitorView view;
@Inject
private transient Conversation conversation;

@Override
public void initializeView() {
    if (conversation.isTransient()) {
        conversation.setTimeout(1800000);
        conversation.begin();   
    }
    MonitorUser user = monitorUserService.findOrCreateUser();
    view.setUser(user);
    List<MonitorElement> elements = monitorService.findMonitorElementsByUser();
    view.setElements(elements);
    view.setUsersMonitorElements(elements);
    createDashBoard();
}
```

This is my method for creating the dashboard, adding panels and setting the column widgets:

```
public void createDashBoard() {

    final int DEFAULT_COLUMN_COUNT = 3;
    int columnCount = DEFAULT_COLUMN_COUNT;
    Dashboard dashboard;

    FacesContext fc = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    Application application = fc.getApplication();

    dashboard = (Dashboard) application.createComponent(fc, "org.primefaces.component.Dashboard", "org.primefaces.component.DashboardRenderer");
    dashboard.setId("dashboard");

    DashboardModel model = new DefaultDashboardModel();
    for( int i = 0; i < columnCount; i++ ) {
        DashboardColumn column = new DefaultDashboardColumn();
        model.addColumn(column);
    }
    dashboard.setModel(model);

    view.setModel(dashboard.getModel());

    view.setDashboard(dashboard);


int index = 0;

    for( MonitorElement i : view.getUsersMonitorElements()) {

          Panel panel = (Panel) application.createComponent(fc, "org.primefaces.component.Panel", "org.primefaces.component.PanelRenderer");
            panel.setId("id" + i.getId());
            panel.setHeader("Dashboard Component " + i.getApplicationName());
            panel.setClosable(true);
            panel.setToggleable(true);

            dashboard.getChildren().add(panel);
            DashboardColumn column2 = model.getColumn(index%columnCount);
            column2.addWidget(panel.getId());
            HtmlOutputText text = new HtmlOutputText();
            text.setValue(i.getCount() + "" );

            panel.getChildren().add(text);
            index++;
    }
    view.setModel(dashboard.getModel());

    view.setDashboard(dashboard);

}
```

I am implementing the dashboard on my index page using:

```
<p:dashboard id="dynamic_dashboard3"
            binding="#{monitorView.dashboard}">

        </p:dashboard>
```

Comment: What is ViewInitializer that you implement?

Comment: ViewInitializer is just an interfaces that has the void initializeView() method, which is called upon view creation